# Slide over effect with css transition - div shows before slide

Tags: html, css

I hope, this question wasn't asked before, but I searched the net and didn't find an answer.

I'm trying to do a slide over over an image. There are lot's of examples in the internet, but they don't seem to work for me.
The slide works, but the sliding div shows before and out of the target image.

Here is my code:

```css
   div.details {
     position: absolute;
     left: -250px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 240px;
     height: 170px;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 5px;
     opacity: 0.7;
     background-color: grey;
     color: white;
     transition: all .5s;
     display: block;
     transition: all 0.5s;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s;
   }
   div.project:hover div.details,
   div.project-nl:hover div.details {
     left: 0px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <a class="fancybox" href="/index.php/assets/Uploads/th2.jpeg">
    <img src="/index.php/assets/Uploads/_resampled/SetSize250180-th2.jpeg" alt="Project2" />
    <div class="details">
      <h2 class="ptitle">Project2</h2>
      <p>Nullam suscipit diam et leo malesuada finibus. Pellentesque hendrerit porta sodales. Suspendisse volutpat eros sapien, et ullamcorper orci condimentum vitae. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
        Maecenas auctor auctor.
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is how I found it in the net, and there it works fine, just, that when I try it, the sliding div is visible all the time.
Is there a way to hide the div, and just show it when it enters the image?
I tried display:none, but then the div just appears, without a slide effect.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just posted it, an now I got the answer.
I have to set `overflow:hidden;` on the containing (`div class=project`) div.